# Error: "Objects are not valid as a React child." when using custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use custom hooks as it's explained in exercise 7.4. here: https://fullstackopen.com/es/part7/hooks_personalizados#ejercicios-7-4-7-8.

For this, I have a CreateNew component which will create new anecdotes:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useField } from '../hooks'

const CreateNew = (props) => {
  // const [content, setContent] = useState('')
  // const [author, setAuthor] = useState('')
  // const [info, setInfo] = useState('')

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const content = useField('text')
  const author = useField('text')
  const info = useField('text')

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    props.addNew({
      content,
      author,
      info,
      votes: 0
    })

    navigate('/', { state: { created: content.value }})
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>create a new anecdote</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          content
          <input {...content} />
        </div>
        <div>
          author
          <input {...author} />
        </div>
        <div>
          url for more info
          <input {...info} />
        </div>
        <button>create</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )

}

export default CreateNew
```

The definition of the custom hook is the following one:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export const useField = (type) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  return {
    type,
    value,
    onChange
  }
}
```

When I try to create a new anecdote, this error is displayed:
`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, value, onChange}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I've also tried sending each property individually (<input type={content.type} [...]) and the error persists.

Am I doing something strange? Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is the file where the error happens? When you call `props.addNew(/* ... */)`, what does that do?

Comment: `content` is an object, so the error makes sense. You should read the actual documentation: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks

Comment: Yep, the problem was that the function "addNew" was waiting for a string and the hook didn't define the field `content` as string. I fixed it passing it to addNew as `content.toString()`.